# sFTP with multiple consumers and idempotent routes: file exceptions

Tags: apache-camel

I have a couple of Camel routes that are processing files that are located an sFTP server. There are multiple nodes running the application where the routes are located, so I have added file locking to ensure only a single node process each file.

The route URI looks like this (split over multiple lines for readability):

```
sftp://<user>@<server>:<port>/<folder>
    ?password=<password>
    &readLock=changed
    &readLockMinAge=10s
    &delete=true
    &delay=60s
    &include=<file mask>
```

The route looks like this:

```
from(inUri) //
    .id("myId") //
    .idempotentConsumer(header(Exchange.FILE_NAME), messageIdRepository) //
    .eager(true) //
    .skipDuplicate(true) //
    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Processing file:  ${file:name}") //
    // Save original file in archive directory.
    .to(archiveUri) //
    ... do other stuff...
```

Every now and then, I'm getting what looks like file contention warning messages:

```
Error processing file RemoteFile[<file>] due to Cannot retrieve file: <file>. Caused by:
[org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException - Cannot retrieve file: <file>]
org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot retrieve file: <file>
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.SftpException: No such file
```

... and also these:

```
Error during commit. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException - Cannot delete file: <file>]
org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot delete file: <file>
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.SftpException: No such file
```

Have I missed anything in my setup?

I've tried adding the idempotent repository to the input URI, like this:

```
sftp://<user>@<server>:<port>/<folder>
    ?password=<password>
    &readLock=changed
    &readLockMinAge=<minAge>
    &delete=true&delay=<delay>
    &include=<file mask>
    &idempotent=true
    &idempotentKey=$simple{file:name}
    &idempotentRepository=#messageIdRepository
```

... but am getting the same kind of errors.

I'm using Apache Camel version 2.24.2.

Comment: Just checked and the files mentioned in the error messages are being processed more than once, so there seems to be an issue with the locking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File locking and multiple nodes is (in my experience) **not very reliable**. When the clients are distributed, a distributed file lock must be supported and I don't know what the FTP layer adds to this mix, but I don't think it makes it easier.

Normally, these errors you get are "just" from the one node that **tries to process an already processed (and therefore deleted) file**. So they are **not a real problem** and if you can live with them, your setup works probably correct (files are not really processed multiple times).

What I usually do, is

- Use `initialDelay` and `delay` options to **avoid that all nodes are polling at the same time**
- Use the option `shuffle=true` so that **every client shuffles the file list randomly**. That lowers the chance that all clients try to process the same file

These are as well not reliable, they can at most be an improvement.

The only way to reliably avoid processing the same file with multiple nodes is perhaps by using **just one consumer**. We use this setup in **combination with health checks and automatic restarts** to make sure the single consumer is available.

Notice that adding an **idempotent repository** is worth nothing until you use a **distributed repository** like hazelcast. If you only use a local repository (or just in-memory repository), it is individual per node and therefore just avoids that the same client processes the same file multiple times.

**Update due to comment**

When you got a distributed idempotent repository and files are processed multiple times, the repository does not work. I can only assume some things that could be the source

- The repository does nothing (check for entries)
- You have to set `readLock` to `idempotent` to "enable" the repository for the file component
- For whatever reasons the same file from different nodes has different idempotency IDs (check in your repo) and therefore they are not recognized as duplicates

Unfortunately the `idempotent` setting of `readLock` is only supported for the [file component](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/file-component.html), not for the [FTP component](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/ftp-component.html).

There is also an `inProgressRepository`. You could also try to attach your repository with this option.

Comment: Thanks for this. A couple of comments: I'm using a JDBC repository, so that shouldn't be an issue. Secondly, I can see that files are processed more than once, which is not what we need to happen.

Comment: I have updated my answer. The distributed idempotent repository should be enough to make sure that no duplicates are processed. I've added some possible problems why the repository does not work.